# Laravel Order By a alias

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

in code below i get a user_name columm not found if i remove my "workaround", how i can set the alias before the get command? have a trick?

```
    //Select
    $qb = DB::table('log as l');

    //Joins
    $qb->join('user as u', 'l.user_id', '=', 'u.id');

    //Orders        
    if($sort[0]["field"]=="user_name")// This is a workaround for my problem
        $sort[0]["field"] = "u.name";

    $qb->orderBy($sort[0]["field"],$sort[0]["dir"]);

    //Wheres
    Data::applyFilter($qb,$filters);

    $total = $qb->count("l.id");

    $qb->skip($skip)
       ->take($take);

    $result = $qb->get(array("l.id", "l.action", "l.entity_type", "l.entity_id", "u.name as user_name", "l.datetime"));
```

Comment: the `user_name` comes from outside the query. that is not a workaround. that is the only way around.

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries) there is

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name as user_name')->get();
```

If you set a key-value variable instead of "user_name" it should do what you want ?

Bye

Comment: I try this but get with nothing override select and user_name not exist again, thanks!